# How can I pass the value of a variable to a text area using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

heres my code:
How can I pass the value of a variable to a text area using JavaScript?
Thanks for everyones help!

```
var overtimeRate = 1.5;
var regularHours = prompt("How many regular hours?");  
var overtime = prompt("How many overtime hours?");


var hourRate = prompt("What is the hour rate of pay?");
var overtimeRatePerHour = hourRate * overtimeRate;
var pay = regularHours * hourRate;
var overtimePay = overtime * overtimeRatePerHour;

function calculator() {
document.write(pay);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(overtimePay);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(overtimePay + pay);
}

document.getElementById("textarea").value = calculator();
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return any value.  Also your function performs `document.write()` so I am confused at to what you are trying to do here?

Comment: ok lets say i want the function to write the variables into the text area is it possible?

Comment: If you want to write to the text area in the function you should look at either CyberJunkie's or user1827711's answer below.  That should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that populates the textarea.

```
function myFunction() {
  var result = pay + '\n' + overtimePay + '\n' + (overtimePay + pay);
  document.getElementById("textarea").value = result;
}
```

Then pop it on an onclick event in the button in HTML.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: ok this worked. but is there any way to not display the "<br>" tag in the text area along with the answer?

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your function like

```
function calculator() {
    var output = pay + '<br />' + overtimePay + '<br />' + (overtimePay + pay);
    return output;
}
```

What you need is the function to return a value which can then be put in the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should not print (document.write). It should return the text like this:

```
var overtimeRate = 1.5;
var regularHours = prompt("How many regular hours?");  
var overtime = prompt("How many overtime hours?");


var hourRate = prompt("What is the hour rate of pay?");
var overtimeRatePerHour = hourRate * overtimeRate;
var pay = regularHours * hourRate;
var overtimePay = overtime * overtimeRatePerHour;

function calculator() {
    var ret = '';
    ret = ret + pay
    ret = ret + '<br>'
    ret = ret + overtimePay
    ret = ret + '<br>'
    ret = ret + overtimePay + pay;
    return ret;
}

document.getElementById("textarea").value = calculator();
```

Comment: make sure you have a textarea or div with id="textarea"

Answer (score 0):

Call the function with an onclick event.

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>`

CyberJunkie just answered, but it seems like they deleted it.

Alternatively, you can use the onchange event with some input tags. This will make it so that the function is performed each time one of the inputs is changed. Instead of Javascript prompts, you would use document.getElementById('element_id').value.

`<form name="myForm">
Regular Hours: <input type="text" onchange="myFunction()" id="regHrs" value="0">
Overtime Hours:<input type="text" onchange="myFunction()" id="overHrs" value="0">
Pay Rate:<input type="text" onchange="myFunction()" id="rate" value="0">
</form>`